# Zabbix - Utilization of housekeeper processes over 75%

Tags: configuration, monitoring, zabbix

I'm monitoring about 1300 hosts on Zabbix. After I defined bulk templates for all hosts, I got the "Utilization of housekeeper processes over 75%" alarm, but it was not resolved for about 20 hours. I did not define a housekeeper in my server settings. How can I resolve this alarm and what is the effect? Using postgresql.

Server config;

```
StartPollers=50
StartPollersUnreachable=50
StartPingers=50
StartDiscoverers=50
StartHTTPPollers=50
CacheSize=1024M
HistoryCacheSize=1024M
TrendCacheSize=1024M
ValueCacheSize=1024M
LogSlowQueries=3000
MaxHousekeeperDelete=5000
```

Postgreqsql config;

```
max_connections = 1000
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 1048kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 12
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 12
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4​
```

[image]

Comment: are you using timescaledb in postgresql? what's in the logs?

Comment: @ironbishop i dont using this extension, i don't see a long running query but housekeeper has been running for over 30 hours.

Comment: what's in the Zabbix logs?

Comment: i dont know how to see housekeeper logs like how many data housekeeper deletes. I have set MaxHousekeeperDelete=750000 but still dont complete

Comment: the content of /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this on Zabbix 5.0 by Administration > General > Housekeeping (drop down) and changing all the 365 data storage periods to 183

That changed peak utilisation from 100% to 59% and average utilisation (housekeeping runs again an hour after it finished) from 6.7% to 0.56%

We never looked at history more than two months old so no functionality was lost for us